# About iAd in my application

Tags: iphone

thanks in advance.
 I have created an application for iphone and am using iAd in that.If i am using ios with version 4.0 then the app crashing because of iAd. But is installing while executing in ios with version 4.1 and later. If any one know the reason please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This crash is due to iAd migration from iOS 4.0, 4.1 to iOS 4.2. The new sdk suggests using ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50 with ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait. Its all ok if its working with 4.1 and above. Just mention to use ios 4.1 and above in your app.